# Preventing div as children in PropTypes only allow one component

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I Have a component that clones child and passes on some new props to it. 
In my PropTypes I only want to allow a React component not anything else. 
For example :

```
<PartentComponent>
  <ChildContent/>
</PartentComponent>
```

It's not always going to be called ChildContent it could be any name for the component.

I do not want parentComponent to allow anything but a component. 
This can not be allowed.

```
<PartentComponent>
  <div>content</div>
</PartentComponent>
```

I tried using in my ParentComponent using a PropType of element. but that still accepts a div

```
Modal.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element,
};
```

The reason I don't want anything but a Component is I pass off props in the cloneElement that can not bee used on a div.

```
  const childComponent = React.Children.map(children, child =>
    cloneElement(child, {
      end: onEndProcesss,
    }));
```

Comment: You can add a custom prop type for by providing a function to the key in your "propTypes" object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with "native" PropTypes API.
But you can create own validator. You can unwrap component type from `type` property of react.element. https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L118

If typeof element.type is string you need to throw error

Example of proptypes typechecker you can find here: https://www.ian-thomas.net/custom-proptype-validation-with-react/

Answer (score 0):

`{React.Children.only(this.props.children)}`

Verifies that children has only one child (a React element) and returns it. Otherwise this method throws an error.

```js
import React from 'react'

function Modal() {
  return(
    {React.Children.only(this.props.children)}
  )

}

Modal.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element,
};
```

Comment: Thanks wootsbot but this still allows <PartentComponent>
  <div>content</div>
</PartentComponent>